# Raised platform around bed with built-in storage

Tags: furniture, storage

I have a small bedroom where I want to build something similar to [this project](http://www.duitang.com/blog/?id=51814489).

[image: Proposed project]

As a start point I want to take [this bed](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/40249876/) and build around it.

[image: Ikea Malm bed]

I tried to found some tutorials (or just articles) which describe similar projects to avoid common pitfalls, but found nothing.

So, I'm looking for any links to tutorials, articles which describe similar ideas.

Any piece of advice also appreciated.

Comment: IMO, you need to narrow down your question.  Is there any specific part of the project that you are unsure about?  Futhermore, a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=storage+around+raised+bed) revealed dozens of articles and videos about raised beds with storage.

Comment: I think this might be too broad. I do understand in concept what you are trying to do but it just looks like you are asking for help for the entire project which cannot be concretely answered in this format. Plus we cannot answer requests for external resources as those are off-topic. You can try asking in chat since you have enough rep and someone might be able to find something for you. If you have a _specific_ problem with the theoretical design we can try to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your searching around for similar projects to help as a starting point for this was just hampered by your wording, as this type of storage is not shelving. So projects with "shelves" or "shelving" as keywords won't match what you're looking for, which I think is most commonly referred to as a platform bed. The storage built into the platform is secondary, and in-floor storage may be what to look for for that aspect of it.

So separate searches for "platform bed" and "in-floor storage" may yield what you need, you could then combine features and build details.

As you might expect something along these lines has already been done by a few people (not least by the person who built the original that you're looking to copy of course) so there's a decent amount out there to find. Here's a link from Apartment Therapy that will at least give you a starting point, [6 Ways to Make Your Own Platform Bed with Ikea products](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/ikea-diy-ideas-make-your-own-platform-bed-with-storage-208433).

If you want to look for a bit more you may have some luck on [Ikea Hackers](http://www.ikeahackers.net/), a search for "bed platform" yields 192 results and one or more is sure to be of some help.